# Response from Jasig CAS

Tags: servlets, cas

I'm working with a servlet in which I want to add filters to log in with cas, and after successful login, i need to get some information from authentication (I need username and usergroup). So, in order to understand how to do that, can someone tell me, or refer me to a documentation, what's the response from CAS and what's in it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using CAS with Spring Security you can use [AuthenticationSuccessHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#form-login-flow-handling) for this. You can get all the information from "authentication" parameter.

If you are not, you can override some methods of the filter you are using for ticket validation. There are onSuccessfulValidation and onFailedValidation methods in [AbstractTicketValidationFilter](http://www.atetric.com/atetric/javadoc/org.jasig.cas.client/cas-client-core/3.2.0/org/jasig/cas/client/validation/AbstractTicketValidationFilter.html) which are empty by default. You can extend the filter you are using and override these methods. The information will be available under "assertion" parameter.

Last of all i think you can create your own filter and in that filter check if the user is logged in and retrieve the desired inforation. But since i haven't used CAS without Spring Security i am not sure the desired information will be available to you there.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not using CAS with SS, but I'll try overriding onSuccessfulValidation method.